# Counting number of different fields in SAS

Tags: sas, summary

I have a table in SAS (using WPS Workbench) that looks like this.

```
ID   Band_1  Band_2 Band_2 ... Band_160
1    Y       Y      N          Y
2    N       N      N          N
3    Y       N      N          Y
4    N       Y      Y          Y
..
200  Y       N      N          Y
```

I want to summarise the table as follows: For each Band, I want a count of the number of Y and N values, with the table transposed (optional).

So down the left will consist of each band, and across the top will be a Y count and an N count. Or the bands can be across the top I don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array processing is one (of several) ways to obtain your summary counts.

```
data have;
  do id = 1 to 200;
    array band(160) $1;
    do _n_ = 1 to dim(band);
      band(_n_) = substr('YN', 1+(ranuni(123)<0.4));
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;

data want1(keep=column yes_n no_n);
  set have end=last;
  array band(160);
  array Yes(160) _temporary_ (160*0);
  array No(160) _temporary_ (160*0);

  * accumulate counts;
  do _n_ = 1 to dim(band);
    if band(_n_) = 'Y' then Yes(_n_)+1; else
    if band(_n_) = 'N' then No(_n_)+1;
  end;

  * emit counts;
  if last then
    do _n_ = 1 to dim(band);
      column = vname(band(_n_));
      yes_n = Yes(_n_);
      no_n = No(_n_);
      output;
    end;
run;
```

The same 'want' data could be obtained from other techniques that use

- Hash object
- Transpose / Report
- Transpose / Tabulate
- Transpose / Freq